# How to automate configuration of ssl certificate on windows azure cloud services during auto scale?

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, azure-cloud-services

I have WindowsAzureCloudService1 deployed with SSL certificate configured.

I have set auto scale configuration to scale up cloud services in order to handle load. Now how to automate the SSL certificate configuration for new instance which gets automatically created by auto scale configuration?

I am not able to find anything over internet by which I can automate this things. I know how to set SSL certificate on cloud services manually from their management portal but I want this to be automated as my end points / instances will scale up / down based on user traffic.

Comment: It just works; the certificate is "applied" to the deployment, not the instance. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes i have tried it but facing issues

Comment: As @Frans said SSL certificates are deployed to the cloud service as a whole; not to each instance of it. If you were to upload a certificate manually through the portal and then scale up the number of instances of the cloud service it should just work. Perhaps if you describe the specific issues you're having we could help more.